# CD Bible Generator Software (not religious)

Tags: html, document-indexing, legal

I've been searching to no avail for software that generates what's commonly known in legal circles as a "CD Bible" - a collection of documents that are linked through a Word or PDF index and burned to CD that can be sent to clients.

Unfortunately Google searches with the word "bible" in them return actual Bible references, so that muddies the waters a bit too much.

I can create one manually in Word and convert to PDF, but I'm wondering if there is any software that can generate an HTML page (that could be opened in a local browser) that contains the folder and file structure of the documents on the CD, and allows end users to browse the document collection easily. The key behind this is being able to generate this HTML output, versus manually coding it (or reverting back to the Word solution).

I've found many "dir to HTML" programs like Snap2HTML, but while they generate the index of a directory and it's contents, the paths are all absolute (e.g., file:\\C:\windows\users...) which would then have to be batch replaced before burning to CD so they are portable.

Ideally this could be given to non-technical people (aka legal assistants and attorneys) that could then generate their own CD bibles.

This would be for Windows, and freeware or commercial software is fine.

Any assistance/advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your first step should be to find  another term than "bible". Your next should be to tell us whether you have a specific operating system in mind (I am guessing MS Windows), and a budget (Or must it be free)? Please read [ask] - the more detail that you can give us, the more that we are likely to be able to help you. If you are a legal person, then you should be well antiquated with presenting things in clear, unambiguous detail

Comment: @Mawg - Thank you - while I work in the legal industry, I am on the software side of things. I've updated my questions to reflect your suggestions.

As for what else to call this software other than "bible", unfortunately that is the commonly known description of this kind of legal document, typically used in M&A (Merger and Acquisition) deals where a book is put together with all the relevant subdocuments linked to an index.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, hence not sure if resolved. But an alternative approach would be to use a "personal wiki" for creating/organising the documents, and then burn to CD.

For instance, you could try [TiddlyWiki](https://tiddlywiki.com/).

You can [embed pdfs and other documents](https://tiddlywiki.com/#How%20to%20embed%20PDF%20and%20other%20documents)

A full list of Wikis can be found [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wiki_software).

Comment: I especially like DokuWiki.